# How to put additional column to WebGrid in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using WebGrid helper to make grid sortable in my MVC application.

```
@{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canSort:true );
        @grid.GetHtml( columns:grid.Columns(

                grid.Column( "Username", "Full Name", canSort:true ),
                grid.Column("Profile","Profile", canSort:false)
            ));
   }
```

**Sortable column will override(display blue link) default style of header how can I maintain that?**

In last column I have image action which will open popup using javascript dialog

```
 <img  title="View Detail" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="openPopup('@item.EncryUserId')"
                            src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/view-fullscreen.png")" />
```

**How can I add this additional column using WebGrid?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got answer as per below

```
   grid.Column(header: "Details",
                format: @<text><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/view-fullscreen.png")"
                 style="cursor: pointer" onclick="openPopup('@item.EncryUserId')"                                                                        
                 alt="View Detail" title="View Detail"/></text>)
```

and inside header there is anchor tag so i have added **headerStyle: "tdheader"**
and add new style **.tdheader a{ color: white};**

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.Column(format: 
    @<img title="View Detail" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="openPopup('@item.EncryUserId')" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/view-fullscreen.png")" />
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but you missed @text which responsible to include html in (@) code section..