# Add links into a webgrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I'm working on an mvc .net web application. I used a webgrid to show data from my database.

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage:true , rowsPerPage :6);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
      @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", htmlAttributes: 
      new {id="datatable" },headerStyle: "Header", alternatingRowStyle : "alt",
      columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("Nom"), grid.Column("Prenom"),     
      grid.Column("Email")));
}
```

I just want to add 3 action links to each row. how to do that. Here are my action links (I used images instead of text)

```
<a href="@Url.Action( "Details", new { id = item.id_client })">
    <img src="~/Images/details.png" alt =""/></a>
<a href="@Url.Action( "Edit", new { id = item.id_client })">
    <img src="~/Images/modifier.png" alt =""/></a>
<a href="@Url.Action( "Delete", new { id = item.id_client })">
    <img src="~/Images/supprimer.png" alt =""/></a>
```

Comment: In fact, those links are for editing, deleting and showing details about each row. Help please

Comment: you want images only or even text is cool ?

Comment: in fact i've found a way using text but i want images ^^ thank you anyway, yasser

Comment: OK, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9341104/1182982) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4901984/1182982) you should get it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Muliple answers from SO

**[Method 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4898715/1182982)**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id=MyId })"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Image.bmp")", alt="Edit" /></a>
```

**[Method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9341104/1182982)**

```
grid.Column(header: "Details",
            format: @<text><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/view-fullscreen.png")"
             style="cursor: pointer" onclick="openPopup('@item.EncryUserId')"                                                                        
             alt="View Detail" title="View Detail"/></text>)
```

**[Method 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496135/1182982)**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", @item.Price, new { @class = "imgLink"})

.imgLink
{
  background: url(YourImage.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Choose wisely ;)

**[Update](http://yassershaikh.com/introduction-to-webgrid-in-mvc-3-razor-with-code-samples/)** :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new{@postID =@item.PostID}, new { @class = "imgLink"})
```

Comment: cool but i have problem here i got an IEnuerable model for my view and I don't know how to pass the id of the current row as a parameter for the action link `@model IEnumerable<GestionProjet.Models.client>`

Comment: which of the 3 method are you using ?

Comment: here is the solution : `grid.Column("","",format:(item)=> @Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new {id =item.id_client}))`

Comment: one last question Yasser ^^. I want all those links to appear in the same column, how to do that?